# Magento - Fatal error: call to a member function getid() on null in app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Type/Configurable.php on line this line

Tags: magento-1.9, fatal-error

I am exporting related images data from **CWS Extensions** extension 
and I am getting an error by this line.

```
public function getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product = null)
{
    $res = array();
    foreach ($this->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
        $res[] = array(
        'id'             => $attribute->getId(),
        'label'          => $attribute->getLabel(),
        'use_default'    => $attribute->getUseDefault(),
        'position'       => $attribute->getPosition(),
        'values'         => $attribute->getPrices() ? $attribute->getPrices() : array(),
        'attribute_id'   => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getId(), // i am getting  error in this line
        'attribute_code' => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode(),
        'frontend_label' => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
        'store_label'    => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel(),
        );
    }

    return $res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check current product is configurable product or not

```
public function getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product = null)
{
    $res = array();
    if (Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_CONFIGURABLE == $product->getTypeId()) {
        foreach ($this->getConfigurableAttributes($product) as $attribute) {
            $res[] = array(
                'id'             => $attribute->getId(),
                'label'          => $attribute->getLabel(),
                'use_default'    => $attribute->getUseDefault(),
                'position'       => $attribute->getPosition(),
                'values'         => $attribute->getPrices() ? $attribute->getPrices() : array(),
                'attribute_id'   => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getId(), // i am getting  error in this line
                'attribute_code' => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getAttributeCode(),
                'frontend_label' => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getFrontend()->getLabel(),
                'store_label'    => $attribute->getProductAttribute()->getStoreLabel(),
                );
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answer I tried But still its showing same Error

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that you have deleted an attribute that was still used for configurable products. Examine on which attribute you get the error, and remove it from your configurable products.